# Could not find a declaration file for module 'solc'

Tags: solidity

i found that "const solc = require('solc');" is returning an error which says

Could not find a declaration file for module 'solc'.

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

This is caused you have some missing npm packages. have you tried running

```
npm i solc
```